# VirtualBox: NAT port forwarding from Windows to Ubuntu does not work

Tags: virtualbox

I am not able set port forwarding Windows 10 host to Ubuntu 19 guest when using NAT.

I have added a rule for Ubuntu VM:

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 19" --natpf1 ",tcp,,8081,,8081"
```

On Ubuntu I have setup server with netcat:

```
$ nc -l 0.0.0.0 8081 -vvv
Listening on [] (family 2, port)
```

On Windows I have tried to send a message but it could not connect to the guest:

```
$ telnet localhost 8081
Trying 127.0.0.1...
```

However, when I try to send a message from Ubuntu to Ubuntu it connects successfully:

```
$ telnet localhost 8081
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
haha
```

and I can see same message in `netcat`:

```
Connection from localhost 51766 received!
haha
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit #1*

```
# ifconfig -a
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:42:bc:ef:27  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:00:27:28:b4:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1306  bytes 94378 (94.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1306  bytes 94378 (94.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Did you try setting the forwarding in the VirtualBox GUI? Just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Lenniey Yes, I did. The result is the same.

Comment: Firewall running on your Ubuntu guest?

Comment: @Lenniey Firewall is inactive: `ufw status` returns  `Status: inactive`.

Comment: @Lenniey I've added ifconfig results. Interestingly, there's no inet address for `enp0s3`. Is that expected for NAT setup?

Comment: Uh, yes, your guest should have a NAT IP, probably in the range `10.x.x.x/xx`